# Should [squashfs] be quashed (or washed)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across [squashfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squashfs) during a close-vote review. This tag currently has 44 questions (some of which are already closed, others have pending close-votes).

From what I can tell (from its wiki-excerpt), this tag is for questions that would seem to be implicitly about general software – it's a tool and not, IMHO, specifically programming-related (although it may be of *use* to programmers).

Should we remove this tag while it still has only a low question count? Or is it likely to be relevant for genuinely on-topic questions?

---

EDIT: After the [comment from Erik A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406663/should-squashfs-be-quashed?noredirect=1#comment836022_406663), it seems that, perhaps, another (better?) option would be to write a clearer tag-Wiki (+excerpt), explaining that this is a file-system but that only programming-related questions are on-topic. As it stands (and as I understood it), the tag appears to relate to a specific, command-line tool.

Comment: It's a file system. Programmers often encounter issues when working with specific file systems, and having a tag for them is sensible. We have tags for most common filesystems (ntfs, ext3, ext4, zfs, apfs, etc). And they all attract some off-topic questions, and some on-topic ones as well. I wouldn't burninate this one, but rewriting the excerpt might be a good idea, I don't think the command line tools are on-topic.

Comment: @ErikA [citation required] Please find a single question on this tag that would be specific to programming.

Comment: @Braiam Wouldn't either all file system tags be acceptable here or none? I've certainly had programming problems that were file system specific in the past, so they seem reasonable.

Comment: @ErikA Fair comment - see edit.

Comment: @Braiam what about e.g. difficulties with packaging an application as an AppImage for Linux? That would be on topic and could definitely involve squashfs

Comment: Agree on the suggestion of updating the tag wiki, that's something that should be done, since it's clearly misleading on its current state.

Comment: @Marc But the Wiki excerpts for many/most of the other file system tags that Erik listed also need updating. I looked at a few and none of those has any sort of usage guidance.

Comment: @JaredSmith again, link a question on the site that does that. Talking in the abstract is not helpful. If all questions are closed, by the virtue of how the system works, the tag will be removed eventually.

Comment: @Voo ideally, a tag about a library rather than a filesystem is the one that should be accepted. But again, most programmers shouldn't worry about the filesystem and only ops guys are the one that should do so. (I weep every-time a poor programmer has to worry about operations tasks)

Comment: @Braiam I'd say [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54681716/7296893) is on-topic, Bazel is a tool commonly used by programmers, and the issue is unique to software development.

Comment: @ErikA and it's not a squashfs question, but a Bazel one as you helpfully point out ;D. As you can see, the only relation with sqashfs wasn't about a library, but how to configure bazel to generate a tarball to then just feed that (manually) to the userspace tools.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree, Bazel can make squashfs files, and the author wants to make a squashfs file with a specific directory structure. The only oddity about that question is that the accepted answer creates tar files, not a squashfs file system, but that's a problem with the answer.

Comment: @Braiam Removing the tag doesn't make it a non-squashfs question. If the wiki for squashfs were better, then I think the tag would be suitable in that question. But I agree with your removal of the [linux] and [build] tags.

Comment: @ErikA no, Bazel can't make sqashfs files. Bazel can make tar files so that the user can feed that to the userspace tools. You could do that to make a cpio stream, etc. There's nothing special or programmatically about it. If the user wanted to make a xz tar file, would it make it a xz question? In your worldview the answer is yes, in my worldview, without using the xz libraries the answer is no. Squashfs doesn't even have libraries to do so.

Comment: @AdrianMole considering that squashfs tools exist only on linux, removing Linux without removing sqashfs makes absolutely no sense. Tho' squashfs does imply linux kernel.

Comment: @Braiam Surely someone writing a backup tool who has a question about say NTFS change journals (did I ever ask a question on those here? It's possible) should tag their question ntfs. So clearly file system tags make sense in some situations. I don't know anything about squashfs, but I assume squashfs also offers an API that can be called programmatically. You don't necessarily need any third party libraries to interact with file systems.

Comment: @Voo nah, if that was the case, everyone that is using the html/css tags should use the website tag (which we removed btw), everyone writing something to compile to binary should also use the binary tag, everyone creating a game should tag with a game tag, etc. Only tools relevant to your problem should be tags, like the language, library, framework you are using, the api you are consuming, etc. you know, things that someone can have an expertise about.